# How to list all supported glyphs of a given font

Tags: command-line, fonts

Is there a CLI command or something to deal with `fontforge` e.g. to quickly get a list of all supported symbols in a given font?

Something like:

```
$ the_command_I_am_looking_for givenFont.ttf
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψωАБВГДЄЖЅЗИІКЛМНОПРСТѸФХѠЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢЮꙖѤѦѪѨѬѮѰѲѴабвгдєжѕзиіклмнопрстѹфхѡцчшщъыьѣюꙗѥѧѫѩѭѯѱѳѵ‫ת‬‫ש‬‫ר‬‫ק‬‫ץ‬‫ף‬‫ע‬‫ס‬‫ן‬‫ם‬‫ל‬‫ך‬‫ײ‬‫י‬‫ט‬‫ח‬‫ז‬‫ױ‬‫װ‬‫ו‬‫ה‬‫ד‬‫ג‬‫ב‬‫א‬ⴱⴲⴳⴴⴵⴶⴷⴸⴹⴺⴻⴼⴽⴾⴿⵀⵁⵂⵃⵄⵅⵆⵇⵈⵉⵊⵋⵌⵍⵎⵏⵐⵑⵒⵓⵖⵗⵘⵙⵚⵛⵜⵝⵞⵟⵠⵡⵢⵣⵤⵥⵦⵧⵯ⵰0123456789+-×÷¢£¥₤₥₦₨₩₪₫€₭₮₲₺ƒ₼₽₴₹฿₵₠Ұ/~`|_-,;:!'"()[]{}@$\&#%+¶‡†‽ 
$
```

Is there a way for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a TrueType font, you can use the [`ttfdump`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/ttfdump.1.html) utility which is available from [TeXlive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/).

```
ttfdump -t cmap -i /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf |
perl -CS -ne 'print chr(hex($1)) if /Char (0x[[:xdigit:]]+)/ and hex($1) != 0xffff; END {print "\n"}'
```

Experimentally, this only seems to list code points below U+FFFF. I don't know if this is a bug in `ttfdump` or if this is because extra work is needed to reach other planes.

For any font that is supported by [Freetype](https://www.freetype.org/), the Freetype library makes this information available, but there doesn't seem to be a readily available command line utility to query it. Here's a one-liner using the [Freetype-py](https://pypi.org/project/freetype-py/) Python bindings, which you can install with `pip3 install --user freetype-py`.

```
python3 -c 'import freetype, sys; stdout = open(1, mode="w", encoding="utf8"); face = freetype.Face(sys.argv[1]); stdout.write("".join(sorted([chr(c) for c, g in face.get_chars() if c]) + ["\n"]))' /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf
```

Comment: Are `fc-list` and `fc-query` **not** reasonable solutions in linux?

Comment: @Isaac They certainly are (well, `fc-query` is, I don't see how `fc-list` helps). I just hadn't found them yesterday.

Comment: A `fc-list :charset=1f63f` lists all fonts that carry a code point (not exactly what was asked but closely related).

Comment: @Isaac Because `get_chars` is passing on the 0 which is an end marker from the underlying C interface. Bad design of the Python wrapper there. But easy to work around, I've edited my answer. Thanks for the bug report.

Answer (score 30):

For fonts that could be used in Linux with fontconfig (almost all).

There are two related questions that usually come from fonts and Unicode:

1. List fonts that could render (contain) a glyph (well, actually, an Unicode code point):

   ```
   fc-list :charset=1f63f | less      # all installed fonts that have 1f63f
   ```
2. List Unicode code points that an specific font covers:

- Look at the table of charset for the font:

  ```
   fc-query /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf  | less
  ```
- List Unicode character ranges for all supported code points (glyphs?):

  ```
   fc-query --format='%{charset}\n' /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf | less
  ```

Both commands could work with an non-installed font file. If the font has been installed, the command `fc-match` does the same work.

The list is not exactly "each glyph", it needs additional work to get there, but is a reasonable clear list of what a font contains.

Since looking to glyphs is a visual task, you need a GUI application to see the glyphs of a font. Printing them on the command line could be done with any font that is configured by the terminal application, not the font you mean to use.

### fontcharlist

You can try the following script (called fontcharlist):

```
#!/bin/bash -

Usage() { echo "$0 FontFile"; exit 1; }
SayError() { local error=$1; shift; echo "$0: $@"; exit "$error"; }

[ "$#" -ne 1 ] && Usage

width=70
fontfile="$1"

[ -f "$fontfile" ] || SayError 4 'File not found'

list=$(fc-query --format='%{charset}\n' "$fontfile")

for    range in $list
do     IFS=- read start end <<<"$range"
       if    [ "$end" ]
       then
             start=$((16#$start))
         end=$((16#$end))
         for((i=start;i<=end;i++)); do
         printf -v char '\\U%x' "$i"
         printf '%b' "$char"
         done
       else
         printf '%b' "\\U$start"
       fi
done | grep -oP '.{'"$width"'}'
```

And get a list of characters in a font like this:

```
$  ./fontcharlist /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf

 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcde
fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌ
ÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒ
ēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘ
řŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸŹźŻżŽžſƀƁƂƃƄƅƆƇƈƉƊƋƌƍƎƏƐƑƒƓƔƕƖƗƘƙƚƛƜƝƞ
ƟƠơƢƣƤƥƦƧƨƩƪƫƬƭƮƯưƱƲƳƴƵƶƷƸƹƺƻƼƽƾƿǀǁǂǃǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔǕǖǗǘǙǚǛǜǝǞǟǠǡǢǣǦǧǨǩǪǫǬǭǮǯ
ǰǴǵǶǸǹǼǽǾǿȀȁȂȃȄȅȆȇȈȉȊȋȌȍȎȏȐȑȒȓȔȕȖȗȘșȚțȜȝȞȟȠȡȤȥȦȧȨȩȪȫȬȭȮȯȰȱȲȳȴȵȶȷȸȹȺȻȼȽ
ȾȿɀɁɃɄɅɌɍɐɑɒɓɔɕɖɗɘəɚɛɜɝɞɟɠɡɢɣɤɥɦɧɨɩɪɫɬɭɮɯɰɱɲɳɴɵɶɷɸɹɺɻɼɽɾɿʀʁʂʃʄʅʆʇʈʉʊʋʌ
ʍʎʏʐʑʒʓʔʕʖʗʘʙʚʛʜʝʞʟʠʡʢʣʤʥʦʧʨʩʪʫʬʭʮʯʰʱʲʳʴʵʶʷʸʹʻʼʽʾʿˀˁˆˇˈˉˌˍˎˏːˑ˒˓˖˗˘˙˚˛
˜˝˞ˠˡˢˣˤ˥˦˧˨˩ˮ˳̀́̂̃̄̅̆̇̈̉
ʹ͵Ͷͷͺͻͼͽ;Ϳ΄΅Ά·ΈΉΊΌΎΏΐΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩΪΫάέήίΰαβγδεζ
ηθικλμνξοπρςστυφχψωϊϋόύώϐϑϒϓϔϕϖϗϘϙϚϛϜϝϞϟϠϡϰϱϲϳϴϵ϶ϷϸϹϺϻϼϽϾϿЀЁЂЃЄЅІЇЈЉЊЋ
ЌЍЎЏАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяѐё
ђѓєѕіїјљњћќѝўџѢѣѲѳҐґҒғҔҕҖҗҘҙҚқҢңҤҥҪҫҬҭҮүҰұҲҳҺһӀӁӂӃӄӇӈӋӌӏӐӑӒӓӔӕӖӗӘәӚӛӜӝ
ӞӟӠӡӢӣӤӥӦӧӨөӪӫӬӭӮӯӰӱӲӳӴӵӶӷӸӹԐԑԚԛԜԝԱԲԳԴԵԶԷԸԹԺԻԼԽԾԿՀՁՂՃՄՅՆՇՈՉՊՋՌՍՎՏՐՑՒՓՔ
ՕՖՙ՚՛՜՝՞՟աբգդեզէըթժիլխծկհձղճմյնշոչպջռսվտրցւփքօֆև։֊؆؇؉؊،ؕ؛؟ءآأؤإئابةتثج
حخدذرزسشصضطظعغـفقكلمنهوىيًٌٍَُِّْٓٔ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٪٫٬٭ٴٹٺٻپٿڀڃڄچڇڑژڤکگھی۰
۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹฿ກຂຄງຈຊຍດຕຖທນບປຜຝພຟມຢຣລວສຫອຮຯະັາຳິີຶືຸູົຼ່້აბგდევზთიკლმნო
პჟრსტუფქღყშჩცძწჭხჯჰჱჲჳჴჵჶჷჸჹჺ჻ჼᴂᴈᴉᴔᴖᴗᴝᴞᴟᴬᴭᴮᴰᴱᴲᴳᴴᴵᴶᴷᴸᴹᴺᴻᴼᴾᴿᵀᵁᵂᵃᵄᵅᵆᵇᵈᵉᵊᵋ
ᵌᵍᵎᵏᵐᵑᵒᵓᵔᵕᵖᵗᵘᵙᵚᵛᵢᵣᵤᵥᵷᵸᵻᶅᶛᶜᶝᶞᶟᶠᶡᶢᶣᶤᶥᶦᶧᶨᶩᶪᶫᶬᶭᶮᶯᶰᶱᶲᶳᶴᶵᶶᶷᶹᶺᶻᶼᶽᶾᶿḀḁḂḃḄḅḆḇḈḉ
ḊḋḌḍḎḏḐḑḒḓḘḙḚḛḜḝḞḟḠḡḢḣḤḥḦḧḨḩḪḫḬḭḰḱḲḳḴḵḶḷḸḹḺḻḼḽḾḿṀṁṂṃṄṅṆṇṈṉṊṋṌṍṔṕṖṗṘṙṚṛ
ṜṝṞṟṠṡṢṣṨṩṪṫṬṭṮṯṰṱṲṳṴṵṶṷṸṹṼṽṾṿẀẁẂẃẄẅẆẇẈẉẊẋẌẍẎẏẐẑẒẓẔẕẖẗẘẙẛẟẠạẬậẰằẶặẸẹẼẽ
ỆệỊịỌọỘộỚớỜờỠỡỢợỤụỨứỪừỮữỰựỲỳỴỵỸỹἀἁἂἃἄἅἆἇἈἉἊἋἌἍἎἏἐἑἒἓἔἕἘἙἚἛἜἝἠἡἢἣἤἥἦἧἨἩ
ἪἫἬἭἮἯἰἱἲἳἴἵἶἷἸἹἺἻἼἽἾἿὀὁὂὃὄὅὈὉὊὋὌὍὐὑὒὓὔὕὖὗὙὛὝὟὠὡὢὣὤὥὦὧὨὩὪὫὬὭὮὯὰάὲέὴήὶί
ὸόὺύὼώᾀᾁᾂᾃᾄᾅᾆᾇᾈᾉᾊᾋᾌᾍᾎᾏᾐᾑᾒᾓᾔᾕᾖᾗᾘᾙᾚᾛᾜᾝᾞᾟᾠᾡᾢᾣᾤᾥᾦᾧᾨᾩᾪᾫᾬᾭᾮᾯᾰᾱᾲᾳᾴᾶᾷᾸᾹᾺΆᾼ᾽ι᾿῀
῁ῂῃῄῆῇῈΈῊΉῌ῍῎῏ῐῑῒΐῖῗῘῙῚΊ῝῞῟ῠῡῢΰῤῥῦῧῨῩῪΎῬ῭΅`ῲῳῴῶῷῸΌῺΏῼ´῾           ‐‑‒–
—―‖‗‘’‚‛“”„‟†‡•‣… ‰‱′″‴‵‶‷‹›‼‽‾‿⁅⁆⁇⁈⁉⁋ ⁰ⁱ⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ⁿ₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₊₋₌₍₎ₐₑ
ₒₓₔₕₖₗₘₙₚₛₜ₠₡₢₣₤₥₦₧₨₩₪₫€₭₮₯₰₱₲₳₴₵₸₹₺₽ℂ℅ℍℎℏℕ№℗ℙℚℝ™ℤΩKÅ℮ⅈ⅐⅑⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅛⅜⅝⅞⅟
↉←↑→↓↔↕↖↗↘↙↚↛↜↝↞↟↠↡↢↣↤↥↦↧↨↩↪↫↬↭↮↯↰↱↲↳↴↵↶↷↸↹↺↻↼↽↾↿⇀⇁⇂⇃⇄⇅⇆⇇⇈⇉⇊⇋⇌⇍⇎⇏⇐⇑⇒⇓⇔
⇕⇖⇗⇘⇙⇚⇛⇜⇝⇞⇟⇠⇡⇢⇣⇤⇥⇦⇧⇨⇩⇪⇫⇬⇭⇮⇯⇰⇱⇲⇳⇴⇵⇶⇷⇸⇹⇺⇻⇼⇽⇾⇿∀∁∂∃∄∅∆∇∈∉∊∋∌∍∎∏∐∑−∓∕∗∘∙√∛∜
∝∞∟∠∣∧∨∩∪∫∬∭∴∵∶∷∸∹∺∻∼∽≁≂≃≄≅≆≇≈≉≊≋≌≍≎≏≐≑≒≓≔≕≖≗≘≙≚≛≜≝≞≟≠≡≢≣≤≥≦≧≨≩≭≮≯≰≱≲≳
≴≵≶≷≸≹≺≻≼≽≾≿⊀⊁⊂⊃⊄⊅⊆⊇⊈⊉⊊⊋⊍⊎⊏⊐⊑⊒⊓⊔⊕⊖⊗⊘⊙⊚⊛⊜⊝⊞⊟⊠⊡⊢⊣⊤⊥⊲⊳⊴⊵⊸⋂⋃⋄⋅⋆⋍⋎⋏⋐⋑⋚⋛⋜⋝⋞⋟
⋠⋡⋢⋣⋤⋥⋦⋧⋨⋩⋯⌀⌁⌂⌃⌄⌅⌆⌈⌉⌊⌋⌌⌍⌎⌏⌐⌑⌒⌓⌔⌕⌘⌙⌜⌝⌞⌟⌠⌡⌥⌦⌧⌨⌫⌵⌶⌷⌸⌹⌺⌻⌼⌽⌾⌿⍀⍁⍂⍃⍄⍅⍆⍇⍈⍉⍊⍋⍌⍍
⍎⍏⍐⍑⍒⍓⍔⍕⍖⍗⍘⍙⍚⍛⍜⍝⍞⍟⍠⍡⍢⍣⍤⍥⍦⍧⍨⍩⍪⍫⍬⍭⍮⍯⍰⍱⍲⍳⍴⍵⍶⍷⍸⍹⍺⍽⎀⎁⎂⎃⎈⎉⎊⎋⎕⎛⎜⎝⎞⎟⎠⎡⎢⎣⎤⎥⎦⎧⎨⎩
⎪⎫⎬⎭⎮⏎⏏␣─━│┃┄┅┆┇┈┉┊┋┌┍┎┏┐┑┒┓└┕┖┗┘┙┚┛├┝┞┟┠┡┢┣┤┥┦┧┨┩┪┫┬┭┮┯┰┱┲┳┴┵┶┷┸┹┺┻┼┽
┾┿╀╁╂╃╄╅╆╇╈╉╊╋╌╍╎╏═║╒╓╔╕╖╗╘╙╚╛╜╝╞╟╠╡╢╣╤╥╦╧╨╩╪╫╬╭╮╯╰╱╲╳╴╵╶╷╸╹╺╻╼╽╾╿▀▁▂▃
▄▅▆▇█▉▊▋▌▍▎▏▐░▒▓▔▕▖▗▘▙▚▛▜▝▞▟■□▢▣▤▥▦▧▨▩▪▫▬▭▮▯▰▱▲△▴▵▶▷▸▹►▻▼▽▾▿◀◁◂◃◄◅◆◇◈◉
◊○◌◍◎●◐◑◒◓◔◕◖◗◘◙◚◛◜◝◞◟◠◡◢◣◤◥◦◧◨◩◪◫◬◭◮◯◰◱◲◳◴◵◶◷◸◹◺◻◼◽◾◿☀☁☂☃☄★☆☇☈☉☊☋☌☍☎☏
☐☑☒☓☔☕☖☗☘☙☚☛☜☝☞☟☠☡☢☣☤☥☦☧☨☩☪☫☬☭☮☯☸☹☺☻☼☽☾☿♀♁♂♃♄♅♆♇♈♉♊♋♌♍♎♏♐♑♒♓♔♕♖♗♘♙♚♛♜♝
♞♟♠♡♢♣♤♥♦♧♨♩♪♫♬♭♮♯♰♱♲♳♴♵♶♷♸♹♺♻♼♽♾♿⚀⚁⚂⚃⚄⚅⚆⚇⚈⚉⚊⚋⚐⚑⚒⚓⚔⚕⚖⚗⚘⚙⚚⚛⚜⚠⚡⚰⚱✁✂✃✄✆✇✈
✉✌✍✎✏✐✑✒✓✔✕✖✗✘✙✚✛✜✝✞✟✠✡✢✣✤✥✦✧✩✪✫✬✭✮✯✰✱✲✳✴✵✶✷✸✹✺✻✼✽✾✿❀❁❂❃❄❅❆❇❈❉❊❋❍❏❐❑❒❖
❘❙❚❛❜❝❞❡❢❣❤❥❦❧❨❩❪❫❬❭❮❯❰❱❲❳❴❵➔➘➙➚➛➜➝➞➟➠➡➢➣➤➥➦➧➨➩➪➫➬➭➮➯➱➲➳➴➵➶➷➸➹➺➻➼➽➾⟂⟅⟆
⟜⟠⟦⟧⟨⟩⟪⟫⟵⟶⟷⦇⦈⦗⦘⧫⧺⧻⨀⨯⩪⩫⬅⬆⬇⬈⬉⬊⬋⬌⬍⬒⬓⬔⬕⬖⬗⬘⬙⬚ⱤⱭⱮⱯⱰⱵⱶⱷⱹⱺⱼⱽⱾⱿ⸘⸟⸢⸣⸤⸥⸮꜈꜉꜊꜋꜌꜍꜎꜏꜐
꜑꜒꜓꜔꜕꜖ꜛꜜꜝꜞꜟꜢꜣꜤꜥꜦꜧ꞉꞊ꞋꞌꞍꞎꞐꞑꞪꟸꟹﬁﬂﭒﭓﭔﭕﭖﭗﭘﭙﭚﭛﭜﭝﭞﭟﭠﭡﭢﭣﭤﭥﭦﭧﭨﭩﭪﭫﭬﭭﭮﭯﭰﭱﭲﭳﭴﭵﭶﭷﭸ
ﭹﭺﭻﭼﭽﭾﭿﮀﮁﮊﮋﮌﮍﮎﮏﮐﮑﮒﮓﮔﮕﮞﮟﮪﮫﮬﮭﯨﯩﯼﯽﯾﯿﹰﹱﹲﹳﹴﹶﹷﹸﹹﹺﹻﹼﹽﹾﹿﺀﺁﺂﺃﺄﺅﺆﺇﺈﺉﺊﺋﺌﺍﺎﺏﺐﺑﺒﺓﺔﺕ
ﺖﺗﺘﺙﺚﺛﺜﺝﺞﺟﺠﺡﺢﺣﺤﺥﺦﺧﺨﺩﺪﺫﺬﺭﺮﺯﺰﺱﺲﺳﺴﺵﺶﺷﺸﺹﺺﺻﺼﺽﺾﺿﻀﻁﻂﻃﻄﻅﻆﻇﻈﻉﻊﻋﻌﻍﻎﻏﻐﻑﻒﻓﻔﻕﻖﻗﻘﻙﻚﻛ
ﻜﻝﻞﻟﻠﻡﻢﻣﻤﻥﻦﻧﻨﻩﻪﻫﻬﻭﻮﻯﻰﻱﻲﻳﻴﻵﻶﻷﻸﻹﻺﻻﻼ￹￺￻￼�
```

Understand that what you see in this web page could have been rendered with some other font and you won't see the exact same glyphs that the font contains.

To actually see the exact same glyphs from a font use `xfd`:

```
xfd -fa /usr/share/fonts/truetype/unifont/unifont_upper.ttf
```

Which is part of the `x11-utils` package.

Comment: Golden answer. Spent an hour looking for exactly this. Thanks.

Comment: I copied your sample output into a `LibreOffice Writer` file and played with the fonts.